# Regex is getting other words

Tags: java, regex

I'm using regex in Java. I want to get only the UpperCase of a String.

Example :

```
1.- M/PS(Obstétrico)          -   group1: M    group2: PS
2.- M / PS* - Obstétrico      -   group1: M    group2: PS
3.- H / PS Adulto             -   group1: M    group2: PS
```

Now when I use:

```
regex : ([A-Z]+)
```

For the first case is getting: `group1: M`  `group2: PS group3: O`

So I say well I am going to exclude with this pattern:

```
regex : ([A-Z]+[^a-z])
```

But for some reason it's getting some characters like:

- PS(
- PS*

I'm using http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Test:
Input.
H / M *
H (Psiquiatria)
PS*
M / PS Infantil
H / M / PS
M/PS(Obstétrico)

Ouput
H,M
H
PS
M,PS
H,M,PS
M,PS

Comment: It's pretty clear why your second attempt is not working(*not* "a-z" does not do what you think it does), but for clarity, can you list the strings you **do** want to find?

Comment: `[^a-z]` matches any character that is NOT a lower-cased letter, such as the matched `(` and `*`.

Comment: Are you saying you want to find all groups of upper case letters that are NOT followed by lower case letters?  Please clarify whether that's what you want.  If so, you'll need a "negative lookahead", something like `[A-Z]+(?![a-z])`

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: So my expected ouput is: M, PS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i solved with this [/ ]?([A-Z]+)[$/ *()]+ thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use `([A-Z]+)[^a-z]` you will get for each string:

group 1: M

then after next find() you will get again

group 1: PS

Explanation; the regex captures in a group any consecutive sequence of A to Z letters which are followed by something which is not a to z. Thus it will capture M in the first group, then start searching again and capture PS in the first group.

---

For your 3 strings specifically, you can use `([A-Z]) */ *([A-Z]+)` which will give you for each of them:

group 1: M

group 2: PS

Explanation: the regex captures a single A to Z letter which is followed by a space 0 or more times, followed by a slash (/), followed by a space 0 or more times, followed by capturing a sequence of A to Z letters. Thus it will capture M in the first group, move through the possible spaces and slash, and capture PS in the second group.

Comment: the 3 strings is individually processed. when i use this expression .The reggex is getting M/ , PS*

Comment: The bottom one works just fine, either you are inputing it wrong or the strings you gave are wrong.

Comment: @Makoton None of the regex in my answer can capture a (/) or a (*).

Comment: I thry this in the webpage. and is something wrong. some of nulls

Comment: @Makoton Put `([A-Z]) */ *([A-Z]+)` in the "Regular expression" field, then put `M/PS(Obstétrico)` and your other strings in "Input 1" through "Input 3" fields.

Comment: but it could have whitespace between characters: M /  PS or M or M  /   P   -  Hospital .

Comment: @Makoton As the explanation in my code states, whitespaces are accounted for. I suggest you do exactly as I described in my previous comment and show me if the output for the strings you provided is different. If you have different strings, you **have** to show their structure to us.

Comment: PS Adulto*,
M / PS*,
H Psiquiatria Infantil,
Output:
PS,M,PS,H

Comment: @Makoton Yes, that's what you specified should happen. What did you want to get?

Comment: i modified my question but i solved with this pattern[/ ]?([A-Z]+)[$\/ \*\(\)]+

Answer (score 0):

You can extract all uppercase terms as an array in just one line:

```
String[] uppers = input.replaceAll("^[^A-Z]*([A-Z/ ]+[A-Z]).*", "$1").split("[^A-Z]+");
```

This works by first extracting the leading sequence of interest, then splits on (and discards) intervening non-upper chars.

Comment: This will get the `O` which he clearly stated he does not want. Also, he wanted a regex capture group.

Comment: @user1803551 quite so. I think I've fixed it. thx. (he didn't clearly state it at all, but I see your point, which I didn't notice)